# Password authentication failed for user "postgresql"

Tags: database, postgresql, django-rest-framework, python-3.9, postgresql-13

Pls I have downloaded postgresql for Windows and I want to connect my models in Django model file to postgresql database but it keep throwing that error
Name : "django 1",
User: "postgresql",
Password: "bless90",
Host: "local host"

Comment: maybe it's just a typo but "localhost" is a single word. Can you show your settings ?

Comment: Thanks I have resolve it......I was using postgresql as the USER instead of just postgres

Answer (score 0):

The result of those type of error is when u used a wrong word while passing the database config like the Name,User,Host,and password but for my case I used postgresql instead of postgres